# Objects alignment in a GridLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-xml, android-textattributes

I have a such xml markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="13:40"
                android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="0"/>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/originalText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Medium Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_row="1"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="150-220"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In IDE it looks fine:

[image]

But when running the application in the emulator right wing `textView2` not aligned to the right, although I have it in the markup:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try testing in device? I tested your code, and the last text is aligned right in device.

Comment: `GridLayout` does not support android:layout_gravity="". wrap your content in a layout and use that layout as child of GridLayout.

Comment: @KetanAhir , can you give me a correct version of markup, please?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="4">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="13:40"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="0">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="150-220"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="13:40"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="1">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/originalText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="150-220"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_row="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="13:40"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="2"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="2">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="150-220"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_row="2"/>
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It did not help, textView does not move to the edge.